# How do i clear checksums in liquibase gradle?

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I am getting this error liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed: as the checksums are different because I changed the DB schema. Now I do not know how to clear the checksum.

My build type is gradle. How would I clear the checksum with gradle?

Answer (score 4):

You may use [liquibase-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-gradle-plugin).

I suppose, `clearCheckSums` command will work for you.

> clearCheckSums - Removes current checksums from database. On next run checksums will be recomputed.

More about this and other liquibase commands [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html).

Answer (score -1):

try to run this cmd :

```
./gradlew liquibaseClearChecksums
```

For more information take a look on that [link](https://docsstage.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/cli/home.html)